# undefined is not a function while adding event handlers

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a list of buttons and add event listeners for each of it on domloaded

```
     window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {  
        var calKeys = document.getElementById("filters").querySelectorAll("a.Button");
        registerKeys(calKeys);
        var registerKeys = function(inputs){
             for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
                    inputs[i].addEventListener("click", handleCalcKey, false);
            }
        };
        var handleCalcKey = function(){
             alert( "thi sis a test");
        }
     });
```

So my registerKeys method basically takes teh inputs and adds the handler. however it fails as uncaught type error undefined is not a function

Not sure what is going on....

Comment: You know the console (F12) points the exact location of the error ?

Comment: `registerKeys` is defined after it's invoked.

Comment: it fails when it gets to registerKeys

Comment: `a.Button` is anchors with HTML `class='Button'`. Just seeing if you knew that. Also, code is not backward compatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There :

```
registerKeys(calKeys);
var registerKeys = function(inputs){
```

you call a function one line before you define it. The variable declaration is hoisted, not the assignation.

You could do it like this :

```
registerKeys(calKeys);
function registerKeys(inputs){
```

but it's generally not very readable. Unless there's a good reason (there doesn't seem to be one here), it's clearer when values are given before they're used.